# Sending parameter JQuery Function from Button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, model-view-controller

I have a button and click function as you see below. I wanna send @item.Id value as parameter in click function. How can I do that?

```
<button id="buttonEdit" style="color:darkgreen" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditRecord">@item.Id</button>
```

...

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#buttonEdit").click(function () {
    
                    $("#Id").val('parameter');
    
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab the text content with [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/), and assign it to the value attribute of the appropriate element.

```js
$('#buttonEdit').click(function() {
  const parameter = $(this).text();
  $('#Id').val(parameter);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="buttonEdit" style="color:darkgreen" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditRecord">@item.Id</button>

<input type="text" id="Id" />
```

Comment: thanks. Is it also possible to take item.Id from name attribute or something else. Actually Im not gonna use the button as item.Id it will be Edit or Delete. So I need to send it from somewhere else. How can I do that ?

Comment: "Edit" or "Delete" will still be buttons? @MertÇakar

Comment: yes. I think I found the solution with this. const parameter = $(this).attr("name"); @Andy. But now there is another problem I can only get the last number of the item.Id which is 1000. It doesnt set #Id other numbers when I click

Comment: You maybe better off asking a new question with the new full markup/jQuery as a [mcve] so we can all help rather than us trying to work it through in comments. You can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the question edit toolbar to help you add a working example. @MertÇakar